# Getting the relevant data from a VISA resource in Labview to use in pyVISA

Tags: python-3.x, labview, pyvisa

I'm volunteering at a uni lab, and I was tasked with removing the dependency on Labview (among other things).

The only problem there for me is the VISA resource. I have no clue (and can't seem to figure out) what exactly the format of the data being sent is.

The VISA buffer seems to get a string, but I've been told that what's being sent is just numbers (0-255), which makes sense, except for the fact that the buffer receives a string.

When I looked at the com port using MAX I saw that there's a termination character on write only (which does make sense given that the device isn't meant to send any data back)

the baud on the com port also says 96,000, when the block diagram has a higher number getting inputted when initializing the VISA resource (though I didn't check it through MAX after running the thing, so it may just keep going to default until I run it)

The device also doesn't respond to an `*IDN?` query (times out), though I hope it's not a problem since, as mentioned, the device isn't meant to send back data, but I'm assuming whatever chip implements the VISA protocol on that side should also respond. pyVISA throws no errors (even with logging enabled), and any attempt to write just gives me success code 0.

All in all, short of debugging Labview to see exactly what's being fed to the buffer (which I haven't done yet - as a volunteer I'm not sure I'm even entitled to a license of labview on my laptop), I'm at a loss as to how I get all the information I need to imitate what's going on in LABVIEW with pyVISA. Right clicking on the VISA resource and looking at its properties is of little help.

Note: I'm using pyVISA-py as a backend for pyVISA since it seems I also need a license for NI's VISA drivers

Comment: A LabVIEW string (assuming classic LabVIEW not NXG) is equivalent to a byte sequence in Python - there's no encoding or decoding going on. What's the physical connection between the computer and the device? Can you post the relevant section of the LabVIEW code (preferably as a [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/))?

Comment: @nekomatic I meant there are numbers which are also displayed on the GUI as hex, though it makes sense that it was just bytes converted into strings for the GUI (Though I don't recall the connection passing through anything that would do that, maybe the textbox itself also does that). The device and computer are connected via USB. I'll try to get back into the lab on Saturday and make a VI snippet. Not 100% sure i'll be able to get in on a weekend though

Comment: Yes, a LabVIEW string indicator can be configured to display byte values in hex via its right-click menu. It sounds as if this device contains a USB-serial converter and presents as a COM port on the PC? In that case you shouldn't need VISA at all and should be able to use pyserial or something similar. (VISA isn't a protocol, it's the middleware layer that NI use to abstract higher-level communications from the hardware implementation - so you could easily port the same code from a serial-connected to a GPIB- or ethernet-connected instrument, for example.)

Comment: Thanks! that's a relief. I barely ever dealt with any kind of communication so it was had for me to make sense of what exactly VISA is and what to do.